# How to set path to /Library/Frameworks

Tags: applescript

How should I set path to /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework

I did this:

```
 set sourceFolder to (path to library folder)
 set Sdl to (sourceFolder as string) & "Frameworks/SDL.framework"   ----Wrong??? correct way???
 tell application "Finder"

      if exists folder Sdl then
          delete folder Sdl
       end if
  end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

You were real close. the 'path to' returns a : path, not a Posix path, so that slash in your definition of Sdl needs to be a colon :.

```
set sourceFolder to (path to library folder)
set Sdl to ((sourceFolder as string) & "Frameworks:SDL.framework")

tell application "Finder"
    if exists folder Sdl then
        delete folder Sdl
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Happy to help. For more info on path descriptions in you script, see:  http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/external_codes/file_paths.html